# QT 5.4.1 sending value in the form1 mainwidow to form2

Tags: forms, qt, qlineedit

I am a beginner in QT. I would like to send the value back into the LineEdit mainwindow to GraphicsWidget window to make calculations.

mainwindow.ccp

```
int value=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
```

GraphicsWidget.ccp

```
qDebug()<<value;
```

Comment: What problem do you have? By now you've read int value from mainwindow, what do you want to do with GraphicsWidget?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Qt signal and slots. For more information refer the documentation  [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)
2. The implementation  for your case will be something like this in

   MainWindow.cpp constructor

   ```
   GraphicsWidget _graphicsWidget;
   connect(this,SIGNAL(sendLineEditValue(int)), &_graphicsWidget,SLOT(receiveLineEditValue(int)));
   ```

   mainwindow.h

   ```
   signals:
   void sendLineEditValue(int value);
   ```

   mainwindow.cpp

   ```
   void MainWindow::decideToSend(){
   int value=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
   emit sendLineEditValue(value);
    }
   ```

   graphicswidget.h

   ```
   public slots:
   void receiveLineEditValue(int value);
   ```

   graphicsgidget.ccp

   ```
   void GraphicsWidget::receiveLineEditValue(int value){
   qDebug()<<value;
   }
   ```
3. The idea is when ever you `emit` a `signal`, the connected `slot` will be called.
4. An implemetation without `signal slot` is to directly call the `GraphicsWidget::receiveLineEditValue(int value)` from the `MainWindow`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIGNAL&SLOT for that purpose, however if you are new and you dont know anything about SIGNAL&SLOT, you can just pass value to another function.

graphicswidget.h

```
public:
void receiveLineEditValue(int value);
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
GraphicsWidget* _graphicsWidget;
_graphicsWidget->receiveLineEditValue(value);
```